# jQuery Mobile ScrollView only working on vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, scrollview

At a quick glance there seems to be a few questions on SO about lack of vertical scroll. My problem is the opposite, I have vertical scroll but no horizontal. Here's the page in question:

http://bgmobile.sytes.net/dogs/threegenpedigree/1

I must've missed something fundamental... but my JS/CSS-Fu is not strong.

EDIT: I just noticed in scrollview.js it adds the data-scroll attr with value 'y'. I have changed that to 'true' but it still doesn't fix it. I have also removed the opts parameter from the scrollview() call after checking out the defaults, and still it only scrolls on the vertically.

Comment: why do you use scrollview.js in the first place? did you include it just to get the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I can scroll horizontally with Chrome and Firefox. It moves the screen horizontally at least, but it doesn't remain in that position but moves back to the original position.

Comment: I need both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I can also scroll vertically, or even diagonally. I just left it out because you already had it working.

Comment: Yup... I realised that. The trouble is I can't figure out why it's cropping the content horizontally.

Comment: yeah i have this problem also. even if i use data-iscroll='{"hScroll":true,"vScroll":true}' only the vertical scroll works. i hope someone should share the right way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is style issue 
add css like below

```
     .containerstyle{

      }
      .containerstyle > .ui-scrollview-view {
       width: 1300px;/*specify the width you want ,
       put a larger value than your screen resolution*/           
      }
```

and change the code for the div as below

```
      <div data-scroll="true" class="containerstyle"></div>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Well... that seems incredibly obvious now that I see it! Thanks, I didn't quite do it that way but yes, the general idea is I had to specify a width. Would be nice to be able to display the content at full width, whatever that may be.

Comment: @DanyW you can specify the style of the content in containerstyle, you can specify the content width as 100% and for the .ui-scrollview-view as 120%, i think it could work.